# Android как передать String в другой Class

Tags: java, android

Как значение с MyString1 из MainActivity.java передать значение в Alarm.java

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    public class MyClass1{
        public final void MyVoid1(String Mystring2) {
            final String MyString1 = "123"; //Та самая MyString1
        }
    }
}
```

**Alarm.java:**

```
public class Alarm{
     public void onReceive(String Mystring3, String Mystring4){
         .setContentTitle(MyString1)//в итоге должно передаться значение "123"
     }
}
```

Comment: а Alarm отвечает за Activity? Вопрос возник  из-за строчки .setContentTitle?

Answer (score 2):

Можно, например, так передать строку из `Activity` в другой класс:

```
public class MainActivity {
    AlarmListener alarmListener = new Alarm();
    final String message = "123"; // Строка, которую нужно передать

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        transferString(); // Тут происходит собственно передача строки!
    }


    public void transferString() {
        alarmListener.onReceive(message);
    }
}
```

Здесь `MainActivity` - класс `Activity`, из которой нужно передать строку.
Метод `onReceive` класса `Alarm` получает эту строку:

```
public class Alarm implements AlarmListener {
    final String LOG_TAG = "Alarm";

    public void onReceive(String str){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"onReceive: " + str);
    }
}
```

А интерфейс `AlarmListener` нужен для связи этих двух классов:

```
public interface AlarmListener {
    void onReceive(String str);
}
```

И тогда при запуске `MainActivity` в консоли LogCat вы получите строку:

> I/Alarm: onReceive: 123

P.S.: в Java по Code Convention названия методов и переменных должны начинаться с маленькой буквы.